# Simperium 409 errors, what causes this?

Tags: simperium

I am setting up an existing app in iOS6 to work with simperium, all has been going well for a few weeks but today I started seeing these errors.

I deleted the App in Simperium and started with a fresh app but still get the error.

The test case is an upgrade for an existing user who already has data in coredata. so they create the simperium account and this is the first sync simperium does.

```
2012-11-14 10:46:31:931 Simperium POST returned error 409 for change {
ccid = da3d0c7bed984f88872f9e7d7527f0f9;
clientid = "ios-ca84b5cc41cc00962c1141a2854aeee0";
error = 409;
id = 54f58c57de65485f889aa4b30c39c54b;
r =     (
    50a3760437a401650500001b
);
```

}

I also see some of these errors but not so many :

```
2012-11-14 10:44:52:823 Simperium error: transform diff for a ghost member (ghost    <SPGhost: 0x1d6324c0>, memberData (null)) that doesn't exist (showInDropDown): {
o = "+";
v = 0;
```

}

Also this :

Simperium timeout, server didn't respond to GET code 504 (ClipModel82),

Answer (score 0):

The 504 is an expected timeout. The other errors are not expected. 409 is a duplicate change, which is ignored but shouldn't happen. The transform error could be happening if you're making changes via a non-iOS client to an attribute that doesn't exist in your Core Data model.

A couple things to try: use the "iosupdate" branch that is on GitHub as of this writing. It has the latest changes and fixes. Also try `setVerboseLoggingEnabled:YES` and get in touch with us by email, including log output as an attachment (help@simperium.com).